# return new Response return empty data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In cotroller i have getVilla metod which return json response.
I get one villa by id from database in `$villa` variable, and this work fine. When i `print_r($villa)` i have villa object with all data. 
But when i push `$villa` in response with 
json_encode: `json_encode(['villa' => $villa])`, villa is empty...

```
villa: {}
```

```
 /**
     * @Route("/ajax/{id}", name="app_post_front_ajax_villa")
     * @param $id
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getVilla($id, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {

        $repository = $em->getRepository(Villa::class);
        $villa = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

        return new Response(json_encode([
            'villa' => $villa,
        ]));
    }
```

Comment: you can try to send JsonResponse instead of Response 
return new JsonResponse(array('villa' => $villa));

Comment: Same... {"villa": {}}

Comment: an other option is to use JMSSerializerBundle 
'$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
$villa = $serializer->serialize($doctrinevilla, 'json');
return new Response($villa);'

Comment: Off topic but consider using the Symfony function dump($villa) when debugging instead of print_r or var_dump.  The output is much prettier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a json response from a response so you should use JsonResponse instead:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

//...

return new JsonResponse([
            'villa' => $villa,
        ]);
```

However, your array contain an object **$villa**, not an **array**.
So you should either make a new array from your **villa** object or serialize it.

The easy way would be to make a new array from villa :

```
public function getVilla($id, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {

        $repository = $em->getRepository(Villa::class);
        $villa = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

        if($villa){
            $villaArray['id'] = $villa->getId();
            $villaArray['cityNameOrSomething'] = $villa->getCityName();
            //Do the same for other attribute you want to get in your json
        }else{
            $villaArray = [];
        }
        return new Response([
            'villa' => $villaArray,
        ]);
    }
```

The other way would be to use the **[serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)** component so that you do not have to make a new array.
Just follow the [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) on the usage to find the one you want to use.